# Import an existing Git repository into IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, repository

I have a local Git repository with my own branches, stashes and all that jazz, and I'd like to add this repository into IntelliJ IDEA, so that I can manage it, instead of creating a new copy of the repository from within IDEA. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can actually use an existing repo.  Just go to **Open** and open the directory that you want to be your root.  Then select the git repo directory, go to the VCS menu, and select **Enable Version Control Integration**.

That's all it took me.  That was how easy it was on a Mac.  Not sure if the flow is exactly the same on other platforms.

Answer (score 11):

The ideal way is to open the directory in Intellij,not trying to import it from repo. When you open the directory as project, Intellij will ask whether you need to configure VCS.

Or even after creating a project in Intellij,you can goto VCS menu and include into Git repo.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially it's just two steps:

1. Specify VCS root,

   This should be done in **Preferences (`⌘,`) > Version Control**
2. Enable Version Control Integration

   if you can find this option in **Menu > VCS**, good luck, just click it. Otherwise, select **Menu > Help > Find Action...(`⇧⌘A`)**, then type `Enable Version Control Integration`, and just press the `Enter` key.

Answer (score 3):

When you start up intellij and no projects are open, there is a dialog option to "import from VCS".  Choose that instead of create new project or import project.

Comment: Is it possible to choose this when you have no projects open?

Comment: @jon.airey VCS->Checkout from version control see here http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/cloning-a-repository-from-github.html After importing it asks if you would like to create a project from the recently pulled files

Answer (score 2):

On the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA, when the project contains more than one module and one of the modules is already tied to VCS integration, the **VCS > Enable Version Control Integration** menu will not appear. This happens in the case when one of the modules was missing a relevant *.git* directory before the integration was added to the project.

Solved by browsing to the relevant project's *.idea/vcs.xml* file and then adding another line such as:

```
<mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$/../project_name" vcs="Git" />
```

The changes should immediately reflect in the UI (e.g. changed lines will be highlighted).

Comment: This worked for me in IntellIJ IDEA 2019.1.4, but the detection was not immediate. I had to close the project and re-open it again.