# Using Intellij to import existing git project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, git-svn

I'm currently using svn, and I'm using git-svn to checkout the project. I then tried to import the project into Intellij, and it kinda worked, but all the .iml files were red in color (don't know why, no errors as far as I could see).

I then tried what was suggested in this post -
[Import an existing Git repository into IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571451/import-an-existing-git-repository-into-intellij-idea)

ie, opening the directory as a project and configuring the git root, same problem again.

When I try compiling the project I get manifest errors that just says - -manifest while reading manifest file(invalid header field)

My project is a multi-module maven project. Any ideas would be helpful cuz I'm stumped!

Comment: Red files are those that are not added to git. if you `git status` you should be able to see the files you can add. You might want to add `*.iml` to your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: ohh ok, so they're not related to the compilation failures then?

Comment: I don't think so. Just Intellij. Red are untracked files, green are newly added, and blue are modified. They will turn back to white after you commit.

Answer (score 0):

With IntelliJ, you should see those same red files [in the Local Changes view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/adding-files-to-version-control.html):

[image: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2019.2/Git_file_status.png]

Except this time, those red files are clearly listed under the "Unversioned file" section, which shows this is not a compilation error, but a VCS code color convention.