# My IDEA "settings --> version control" doesn't have "git"

Tags: git, intellij-idea

"Git" is missing in my IDEA.
And I don't hava "Enable Version Control Integration" in my "VCS".

Comment: Is it like https://stackoverflow.com/a/50093139/6309?

Comment: Could you please check Preferences | Version Control - do you have your project repository listed there? Could you please share screenshot of VCS menu?
Also please check Preferences | Plugins -> Installed -> do you have Git plugin enabled?

Comment: “Could you please check Preferences | Version Control - do you have your project repository listed there? Could you please share screenshot of VCS menu? Also please check Preferences | Plugins -> Installed -> do you have Git plugin enabled?”  ------- I didn't find it. It was missing.

Comment: "Is it like stackoverflow.com/a/50093139/6309?" ---- Yes. But the answers aren't ok

Answer (score 0):

In market plugins.
Uninstall the "git".
Then install "git".
Will be OK.