# Connect to an existing Git repository in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, repository

I am trying to connect an existing non-empty project to an existing non-empty repository. I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571451/import-an-existing-git-repository-into-intellij-idea) which does not address this.

The title says it all, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first in command-line, before switching to Git.

```bash
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote add origin https://url/existing/remote/repository
git fetch
git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches
```

If you see the same history for origin/main and your local main branch, you have the right remote repository.

Then open IntelliJ IDEA, which should detect the newly added remote `origin` reference.
(Check  `VCS -> Git -> Remotes`)